# How to recompile Android app, adding LeakCanary to the apk?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, heap-memory, owasp

In the [OWASP MASTG](https://mas.owasp.org/MASTG/tests/android/MASVS-CODE/MASTG-TEST-0043/), there said that you can test the Memory Corruption Bugs by recompile the application and use it with [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/)

> Dynamic Analysis
>
> There are various steps to take:
>
> In case of native code: use Valgrind or Mempatrol to analyze the memory usage and memory calls made by the code.
>
> In case of Java/Kotlin code, try to recompile the app and use it with Squares leak canary.

The [document](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/) shows only method to include the library when ones have the source code in hand. My question is how to recompile the application (.apk package) to include LeakCanary for dynamic analysis of memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

After you include the library and rebuild your project, it automatically gets added and just by doing that you will see another icon related to Leak Canary the next time you install the app on your device.

refer to [this](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/) webpage in the Leak Canary documentation.

Comment: I do not have access to the source code of the application. I have only the .apk. Is the described method still valid? I think that without source code I can only "Profile or Debug APK" in Android Studio.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. unless you could somehow de-compile your APK file, add this library and recompile it again. Doing something like that is quite challenging.